# How to make an SQLite database as part of the build process - iPhone SDK

Tags: sqlite, ios4, core-data

I have created a Core Data application in iPhone Simulator. Now when I am testing it on a device, my SQLite database is empty. I have some preloaded settings which I want to deploy when the application is installed.

How can I achieve that?

I have seen a few questions on Stack Overflow, but they don't exactly answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an existing sqlite-store file you just add it to the app bundle just like you would any resource e.g. images, audio, etc.

If it is read only, you just use the NSBundle commands to supple a path to it inside the readonly app bundle. If you want it writable, you copy the store file from inside the app bundle to one of the writable app directories e.g. Documents or Library, and then open it there as you normally would.